# Set Timezone Per Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I am setting the user's timezone per request basis. The user's timezone is kept in the database and then I set the timezone with an around action in the application controller.

However, every once in awhile, seemingly randomly I get an error ArgumentError (no block given): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:84:in `set_time_zone'

And I have no idea why? Anyone do this before? Is there a better way?

I followed this to help me set it up: https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/

application_controller:

```
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

def set_time_zone(&block)
   time_zone = current_user.try(:time_zone) || 'UTC'
   Time.use_zone(time_zone, &block) 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app uses a similar pattern, however we use a before_filter, then

```
Time.zone = @current_admin_user.time_zone
```

Once set it is set for the process, and each process only runs one request at a time.

Comment: thank you. I'll give this a shot and see what happens. I'll try it out for 24 hours and comment back if it works

Comment: This could cause some confusing and subtle bugs on multi-threaded servers. If requests come in one after another, one request can alter the timezone of another.

Comment: Actually, nm. Looking at the source code, they use a thread local variable to store the zone. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L41-L43